# Why most of the sidebar examples have left 250 and margin-left -250?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Looking at most of the examples in bootstrap, I see that sidebars have css of `left:250px` and `margin-left:-250px`.

Why not just have `left: 0px` which would give the same result?

Example:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: *"Why"* questions are often closed for being primarily opinion-based on SO. Try using some of the [tips from this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/5743988) to better get at what you're looking for. Otherwise, you will get answers that just contain speculation and aren't actually canon.

Comment: @4castle It will also help others user in understanding why it is done in such a way. Is it a convention? or thinking on this may lead to new way of achieving it. who knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed in [one project that used the practice](http://www.bootply.com/hHxROO5DmG), there were various `@media` queries that changed the sidebar to have different widths (and therefore different corresponding values for `left` and `margin-left`) at different window sizes.

One feature of doing this is that to hide the sidebar, one could simply call `left: 0`, and it would move the sidebar by its full width regardless of the current width of the sidebar. This is better than using `display: none` because it can be animated to slide off of the screen, and different than calling `width: 0` because the sidebar could still be visible in the case that it wasn't going off-screen.

For example:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".sidebar, .content").toggleClass("hiddenSidebar");
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
.content {
  left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.sidebar {
        width:  100px;
         left:  100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  height: 500px;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .content { left: 50px; }
  .sidebar {
          width:  50px;
           left:  50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
  }
}
.hiddenSidebar { left: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content">
  <button>Toggle Sidebar!</button>
</div>
```